# How to implement FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject using SWIFT code

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have checked in various site n could find the objective-c code :

```
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject alloc] objectWithProperties:properties];
```

While trying to implement the same using SWIFT, I am unable to find `objectWithProperties`.

Can someone help on the same?

Answer (score 1):

Swift uses `[NSObject : AnyObject]!` instead of `NSDictionary`. And `objectWithProperties` becomes `properties` in the initialisation of FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject. So I believe your Objective-C example should be:

```
let graphProperties : [NSObject : AnyObject]! = ["og:type": "video.other","og:title":"Test title", "og:description":"This is a test video"]
let graphObject : FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: graphProperties)
```